# Why does my window.navigate code fail?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<section id="thisitem"...>`

And when I try to do `window.navigate("#thisitem");` JS fails on that line...why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no method `navigate` in `window` in DOM.

Comment: You can do this using `window.location.hash` method

Answer (score 2):

Because `window.navigate()` is IE-specific and not cross-browser compatible.  Use `window.location.href = '#thisitem'`.

Answer (score -2):

i think you mean : `window.location='#thisitem';`

Comment: I am using phonegap...trying to navigate to a certain section of the single HTML file.

Comment: It's a relative URL to a fragment in the same document.  Makes perfect sense.